# AutoFixture + AutoMoq: Create mock with excluded property

Tags: c#, interface, moq, autofixture, automoq

For example `ISomething` is a interface with three properties: `string Name` and `int Count` and some complex property `ImComplex` (with circular dependencies etc) that I don't wanna AutoFixture to build up. So I need AutoFixture to create a Mock of `ISomething` with `Name` and `Count` set up by its default algorithm and `ImComplex` as null. But if I try to solve it like this i get an exception:

```
fixture.Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
var some = fixture.Build<ISomething>().Without(x=>x.ImComplex).Create<ISomething>();
```

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException : The decorated
>   ISpecimenBuilder could not create a specimen based on the request:
>   RP.Core.IInformationUnit. This can happen if the request represents an
>   interface or abstract class; if this is the case, register an
>   ISpecimenBuilder that can create specimens based on the request. If
>   this happens in a strongly typed Build expression, try supplying a
>   factory using one of the IFactoryComposer methods.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Build` disables all customizations (as stated in the method's documentation), so it won't work together with `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`.

If the problem is that the property has a circular dependency then you can either:

1. reconsider your design (the reason why AutoFixture, by default, throws when it finds a circular dependency it because these are usually design smells)
2. configure AutoFixture to allow circular dependencies, up to a certain depth

   ```
   fixture.Behaviors.OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>().ToList()
       .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));

   int recursionDepth = 2;
   fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior(recursionDepth));
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Entity Framework's entities have navigation properties that cause circular dependencies. I've tried to use OmitOnRecursionBehavior but had no success.